# How get HDD current load info in windows?

Tags: c++, winapi

I need once per second get information about HDD loading like (current write speed,current read speed, total loading percent etc.) more info is better. Spesial  functions on Win32 API i dont find. Maybe need very low level functions or i need go to driver level. Please help me solve this problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options, checking the performance of your hard disk by accessing the [S.M.A.R.T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) info or using  the [windows performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083%28VS.85%29.aspx)  you can access these counters using the WInApi or the WMI.

Check these resources

S.M.A.R.T

- [Hard drive information using S.M.A.R.T.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/Hard_drive_Information.aspx)

WinApi

- [Accessing Performance Data in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384724%28VS.85%29.aspx)

WMI Related Classes

- [Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394261%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394261%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394262%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394308%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @RRUZ i know the question is old, but can SMART data be accessed through C ?

Comment: Is S.M.A.R.T. really suitable for short term load info?

Answer (score 2):

The [performance counter APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will help you do what you're attempting to achieve. Unfortunately I have no personal experience using them so can't give you further information.